# JMeter showing Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException error for more than 1000 request

Tags: azure, jmeter

I am testing an application hosted on azure server, for 2000 users using JMeter. But i am getting following errors
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://www.app.com refused

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Read timed out

How to overcome these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application can not handle more than 1000 users and that is what it indicates by the above error.

When you get the error, Are you able to access the application manually?

Comment: I am running the test using non-gui mode and check the error after test is complete. I did not check the application at that time.

Comment: You might want to check the application while running the test. This error does not seem to be a JMeter issue.